# addEventListener not working. Help me to correct an JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

why that is not working ?

```
var headerBanner= $(".header-banner");
var closeBtn = $('closeBtn');

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  headerBanner.classList.add('IsClose');
}, false);
```

```
.closeBtn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0.8; 
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;

}
```

I want to make custom button to close.
in f12 can't see "IsClose". Do I make any mistake in js ?

Comment: jquery doesn't return an element, it returns some jQuery object - did you see the error in the browser console? `can't see "IsClose"` and `seeing IsClose in f12` .... which is it?

Comment: Yes, I have but why ?

Comment: because jquery doesn't return an element (like I already said), it returns it's own jquery object that has no addEventListener method ... have you tried `closeBtn.click(handler)`? if you are going to use jquery, use jquery

Comment: sorry first time usung stack edit I cant see "isClose"

Comment: same issue: 
var headerBanner= document.getElementByClass("header-banner");
var closeBtn = document.getElementByClass('closeBtn');

i didn't just I have no idea why this method is not working in this moment

Comment: `getElementByClass` isn't even a function and `getElementsByClass` returns a collection of elements

Comment: That mean i must read more about jQuery but if you can repair the fundamental mistake in code i will be realy happy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many errors in your code, this is I assume.

First, you are using `jQuery` to select elements, but then trying to use the `addEventListener` which is a native js method. In `jQuery`, you should use the `on` method to attach event handlers. Then, you are using `$('closeBtn')` to select your close button. This is **INCORRECT** because it's trying to select `closeBtn` which doesn't exist. If `closeBtn` is a class, you should use `$('.closeBtn')` instead. Lastly, you are trying to add a class to `headerBanner` using `classList.add`, but `headerBanner` is a `jQuery` object, not a DOM element, so you should use the `addClass` method.

Sample workaround;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var headerBanner = $(".header-banner");
 var closeBtn = $('.closeBtn');

 closeBtn.on('click', function () {
   headerBanner.addClass('IsClose');
 });
});
```

```css
.header-banner {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: #f00;
}

.closeBtn {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
 opacity: 0.8; 
 float: right;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.IsClose {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="header-banner">
 <div class="closeBtn">X</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JQuery's version of `classList.addClass()` and also change the eventListener to `on`:

```js
closeBtn.on('click', function () {
  // 'headerBanner' is a JQuery object:
  headerBanner.addClass('IsClose');
});
```

You can also check to make sure the listener is working correctly by adding `console.log('test')` to your event listener:

```js
closeBtn.on('click', function () {
  // Test that the listener is working correctly:
  console.log('The event listener is working!');
  // 'headerBanner' is a JQuery object:
  headerBanner.addClass('IsClose');
});
```

Also, you need to change your declaration of `closeBtn`:

```js
var headerBanner= $(".header-banner");
var closeBtn = $('.closeBtn'); // '.' selects a class, like in CSS
```

It is worth noting that it's recommended to use an `id` for the elements you want to use for JQuery that act as triggers, for example:

```html
<button class='class-here' id='myElement'>Click Me</button>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  // Get the element
  const myElement = $('#myElement');
  // Attach an event listener using JQuery's element.on():
  myElement.on('click', () => {
    console.log('Button clicked!');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I made an oopsie in my original answer, I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

`headerBanner` is not a single element, so you should give function all those elements.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var headerBanner = $(".header-banner");
  var closeBtn = $('.closeBtn')[0];

  closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    for(let banner of headerBanner)
      banner.classList.add('IsClose');
  }, false);
});
```

```
<p class="header-banner">Banner</p>
<button class="closeBtn">close</button>
```

Comment: @1skora, because `headerBanner` and `closeBtn` are all class name. So, variable `headerBanner` and `closeBtn` are all array, not single element.

Comment: You should fix `var closeBtn = $('closeBtn');` to `var closeBtn = $('.closeBtn');`

Comment: You could just use JQuery's `element.on()` function like in my answer. If you're going to use JQuery, why write JQuery on one line and regular JavaScript on another? Why not utilize the built-in JQuery methods made for this?

Comment: It works, too as you said. But I tried to fix it as small as possible, so I'd like to tell @1skora what he made a critical error.

Comment: Makes sense, but I honestly think it's better (especially because he is just starting out) to maybe explain you could do it that way, but then also offer a JQuery solution and recommend he do it that way anyway (kill two birds with one stone).

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your advice. Your code is good Jquery answer and it could help him. Nice.

Comment: Thanks, I just added on to my answer as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256015/discussion-between-hcharles25-and-quietwind01).